# Question on cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $a=\bigcup_{i\in I_a}a_i$ and $b=\bigcup_{j\in I_b}b_j$ where $I_a$ is the index set of $a$ and $I_b$ is the index set of $b$, such that

1. $\forall i\in I_a:a_i$ is a finite set
2. $\forall j\in I_b:b_j$ is a finite set
3. $a_k\cap a_m= b_l\cap b_n=\emptyset$ if $k\neq m$ and $l\neq n$
4. $\left |a_i \right |\ge\left |b_j \right |$ for every $i\in I_a$ and $j\in I_b$
5. $\left |I_a \right |>\left |I_b \right |$.

Is $\left |a \right |>\left |b \right|$?

Comment: Do you have any conjecture?

Comment: My gut feeling tells me $\left |a \right |>\left |b \right|$. Because there’s an injective function from $b$ to $a$ but not a surjective one.

Comment: You’re almost right: that is true (and can be proved without too much trouble) **unless** all of the sets $a_i$ and $b_j$ are empty.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott there is another loophole (see answer).

Answer (score 2):

Condition 3 is phrased in a very strange way and should ring alarm bells.  If we let $$I_a=\{i_1,i_2\}\quad {\rm and} \quad I_b=\{j_1\}$$ then we can have $$ a_{i_1}=\{1,2,3\},\qquad a_{i_2}=\{1,2,3\},\qquad b_{j_1}=\{4,5,6\}.$$

This satisfies all of the given conditions.  Do you see why it satisfies condition 3 despite appearances?  None the less $|a|=|b|$.

Comment: I’m not sure how this example satisfies condition 3?

Comment: @jshthng if it did not satisfy condition 3, then there would have to be, $k,m,l,n$ for which it fails.  If you think it fails condition 3, you should be able to give me values for $k,l,m,n$, where it fails.

Comment: So, I should separate condition 3 into two conditions. One for $a_k\cap a_m$ and another for $b_l\cap b_n$?

Comment: I was hoping this was a clever question someone had set, where you were supposed to spot the loophole.  On the other hand if it is a question you asked yourself, then you probably meant the version with condition 3 split into two.

Comment: @tkf: Even if someone else had set the question, I’d expect the intent to have been simply to require that the $a_i$ and the $b_j$ be pairwise disjoint, and the loophole to have been an oversight. (And if it **were** intentional, I’d call it a bad and fairly pointless question.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I feel like this kind of reasoning is often a crucial step in proofs of significant theorems, especially for example in the base cases of proofs by induction.  Nothing comes to mind - these are usually the steps you forget once you have checked them.  In an introductory module whose sole purpose is to get students to engage with mathematical notation and thinking it could have a place (or a writing mathematics module).  If jshthnng did think of this question then I think a lot of credit is due for putting it in his\her own terms (+1) and exposing this idea, regardless of intent.

Comment: @tkf: I think that it would be better as an illustration of how easy it can sometimes be to say something just a bit different from what one intended to say. Even in the contexts that you suggest it strikes me as more of a *Gotcha!* question than a genuinely useful or instructive one. (I don’t really believe in either of those modules anyway. In my experience the former requires a whole course (save for the students who don’t need it at all), and the latter is best handled by example and constant feedback on students’ written work.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right that on the two occasions where I taught a first year, first semester module using this philosophy, I was extremely unpopular and the students did think I was going for the 'gotcha'.  Still I do like this question, and if I ever go back to teaching I am looking forward to putting it into a midterm (I would add the hypothesis that $a$ non-empty, to rule out your solution).

Comment: @tkf: It isn’t the popularity or lack of it that concerns me; over the years I certainly had plenty of students who thought that I wanted too much from them! I just think that it’s bad pædagogy.